# Joins in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

I have the following data structure stored in RethinkDB table:

```
{
   id: string,
   parentId: string,
   timestamp: number,
   data: Object
}
```

This data structure forms a tree, it can be depicted using the following diagram (white records represent ordinary data carrying records, the red ones have their `data` property equal to `null` which represents delete operation):

[image: Diagram]

Now for every record in the table I would like to be able to compute the `nextRecord`. Which is the closest record in time to the current one. The task seems simple when there is only one record pointing back to a parent:

```
1 => 2
4 => 9
5 => 6
6 => 8
...
```

But it becomes more difficult to compute such value when parent record is being referenced by several child records:

```
2 => 3
3 => 5
7 => 11
```

The is also case when there is no child reference in which case the result should be `null` (for example record #8 has no child records, and so `null` should be returned).

So I'm not asking to write the query itself (which on the other hand would be really great to me) but at least point out the direction in which I can find solution to this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this efficiently with a compound index on `parentId` and `timestamp`.  You can create the index like this:

```
r.table('data').indexCreate('parent_timestamp', function(row) {
  return [row('parentId'), row('timestamp')];
})
```

After you've done that, you can find the earliest item with parent PARENT like so:

```
r.table('data')
 .between([PARENT, r.minval], [PARENT, r.maxval], {index: 'parent_timestamp'})
 .orderBy({index: 'parent_timestamp'})
 .nth(0).default(null)
```